# telerik-mvc grid - how to format footer template?

Tags: telerik-mvc

This is my code in the controller:

```
[GridAction]
public ActionResult _Select()
{
    // Creating dummy data to bind the grid 
    var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
        .Select(index => new Customer
        {
            ID = index,
            Name = "Customer #" + index,
            Tax = 1 + index,
            Amount = 500 + index
        });


        return View(new GridModel(data));
    }
```

This is what I have in my view:

```
<%: Html.Telerik().Grid<GridLoadedWithAjaxInTabStrip.Models.Customer>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ID).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Tax);
       columns.Bound(p => p.Amount);

    })


    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_Select", "Home")) 
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable()
    .Groupable()
    .Filterable()
%>
```

I would like to know how I can put a custom footer template in this format:

```
Total Tax:       XXXXX
Total Amount: XXXXX
Grand Total:   XXXXXXX
```

Please assist me how I can do this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this demo

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/aggregatesajax

Comment: I already check the demo but could not figure out how to format the way I wanted.  Anyone can help me on this?  Thanks